# Plural noun+with+singular or plural?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. The machines with internal buffer engines work fine.
2. The machines with an internal buffer engine work fine.

(Assume that each machine has one internal buffer engine or none.)

Comment: If there's only one internal buffer engine, then the second one is more accurate but both are correct in general.

Comment: Recast: Every machine with an internal buffer engine works fine.